# How to setup SQL Azure Reporting?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, ssrs-2012

My boss asked me to do some reports with SQL Azure Reporting. I'm quite new to this business, but I already did some reports with success on SSRS, but now I am facing some difficulties on how to setup the SQL Azure Reporting.

First, I tried to enter on Azure Portal and could not find the SQL Azure Reporting.

Am I doing this in the right way?

I already tried to do some research on Google, but I still get stucked on this.

My apologies if this question is too primary.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ssrs has an option to choose azure database

Comment: You can setup the reports and configure datasets in same way as databases in on premises.When configuring datasets choose azure database,unless you want to query multiple databases ,I don't see an issue I where you are stuck

Comment: @TheGameiswar yeah I know that, I'm using SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013 and when I try to connect to an azure database appears an error message saying that I do not have a subscription...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure SQL Database PaaS service does not have an embedded reporting tool. With that said, there are a few options for running SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS):

1. If you have an on-premises instance of SSRS, you can use your Azure SQL Database as a target and create reports
2. If you are looking to run everything in Azure, you can host an instance of SSRS in an Azure VM (IaaS). To accomplish this, there are two scenarios:

   - Provision an instance of SQL Server in an Azure VM and [configure SSRS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-sql-server-business-intelligence/#configure-reporting-services)
   - Provision an instance of Windows Server in an VM Azure, "bring your own SQL Server license", and install SSRS in the VM.
3. If you're not bounded to SSRS, PowerBI (http://powerbi.com/) is great for authoring reports in the cloud.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I still got some questions. 1. Yeah, I can try that approach, but my main goal is to run everything on the cloud. I already tried PowerBI but does not satisfy our needs. How can I host an instance of SSRS in Azure? Glad for your help.

Comment: You must to use SQL Server on a Virtual Machine.  You can choose one of the gallery. SQL Server 2012 or 2014 are available.  You can use D or DS machines.  They could work fine for SQL Server

Comment: @JulianCastiblanco You refer to an Azure VM?

Comment: Yes Sr. As @Joseph Idziorek comment in his answer. this is the way for use SSRS on the cloud